# How do I automate suppling the network location of the kickstart config file when booting a Redhat variant 7 install iso

Tags: centos, redhat, fedora, kickstart, scientific-linux

When booting a Scientific Linux 7 install iso for example, one could immediately hit tab and add some text to specify the location of the ks.cfg file they would like to use.

I would like to automate this completely so no human intervention is needed.

As a general example I may have a Jenkins job that connects to an HP ILO, inserts an iso, and triggers a reboot.

What I have not found an answer for yet in Googling is how to automatically append something like:

```
linux ks=http://<location>/ks.cfg
```

to the end of the config line that appears after you hit tab.

My ideal solution would be to use few to none in regard to third party provisioning tools.

Ultimately I plan on using Jenkins, puppet, pxeboot, etc, but I dont want the solution to be dependent on something like cobbler for example.

Comment: The solution _is_ dependent on your chosen provisioning method, so answering _this_ question won't help you. Providing the command line via PXE has absolutely no relation whatsoever to providing it to a CD/DVD based installation.

Comment: If that is the case, then if I had jenkins connect to ILO, insert a dvd iso, how would I automate the appending of the ks.cfg url?

Comment: Normally I'd modify the ISO image ensuring the correct options are included in the default isolinux boot option. But typically when you'll be retrieving the kickstart file from the network and remote mounting an ISO image you want that ISO to be small and do a network install, not a CD/DVD install.

Comment: Ah, yes this is basically what I was looking for, I found the isolinux.cfg file which contains that line to append. In my case when we move servers from one data center to another, the network team frequently does not get the vlan change request right and network dependent boot iso fail first. I wanted something that was not network dependent upfront which I why I choose a full DVD

Answer (score 0):

Just to clarify the answer for others:

Create a custom iso:

http://smorgasbork.com/component/content/article/35-linux/151-building-a-custom-centos-7-kickstart-disc-part-1

These directions were sufficient for this part.

In the isolinux folder edit the isolinux.cfg file.

Here it looks like you could add multiple install options as well that look like:

```
label check
    menu label Test this ^media & install SL 7
    menu default
    kernel vmlinuz
    append initrd=initrd.img inst.stage2=hd:LABEL=SL-7-x86_64 rd.live.check quiet
```

After the word quiet add:

```
ks=http://location/to/ks.cfg
```

What I like about this It appears I could add multiple options for different scenarios perhaps.

I will test this and update the thread

This link contains all the possible ks location options.

https://access.redhat.com/documentation/en-US/Red_Hat_Enterprise_Linux/5/html/Installation_Guide/s1-kickstart2-startinginstall.html